# fb share button asks for fb credential when webpage is loaded from android webview

Tags: android-webview, facebook-share

I am loading my website through webview of android. The webpage contains fb share and comment plugins. Now when i try to share page it asks me to login my fb credentials in webview which i don't want to happen. What i want is android fb app to handle my login. Is there any way to redirect the facebook login dialog from webview to android fb app.

Second Approach:
I have also tried loging the user in by using fb android sdk and loading the webpage via webview. Now can i use access token from android sdk to login the user in webview.

here is my code:

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String url ="http://kantipur.ekantipur.com/news/2016-01-10/20160110073954.html";
        WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl(url);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
```